# Jquery UI in conflict with Bootstrap in CSS

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I found many conflicts in css definition when I integrate Bootstrap and Jquery UI.
For example, there are `h3` css definitions in both. So for this case, I always have to comment one of them.

My original idea is using the Bootstrap for the page layout and using Jquery UI to build UI interaction.

Is there any easy way to integrate them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a specific theme for jQuery UI that provides support for Bootstrap: https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery-ui-bootstrap

Comment: Hi, @Josh , Is there any possiblity to use the custom download and themeroller of the jquery ui as well as the jquery-ui-bootstrap? thanks.

Comment: @Joe.wang - I've only used it a couple of times, and mostly just for the Datepicker :) My understanding is that this is a departure somewhat from the current Themeroller style themes provided in jQuery UI. This is the stuff that breaks when combined with bootstrap.

Comment: Hi, @Josh,Hehe , Both of them are the same staff for build web end ui. They are from two different group dev team, one is jquery dev team . another is twitter dev team. but I do think the bootstrap is better than jquery ui in the layout design.Thanks,