# Keep jQuery datetimepicker open

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

Let me share my exact scenario.
I have two inputs

```
<input type="text" id="dt1" readonly="readonly" />
<input type="text" id="dt2" readonly="readonly" />
```

I have set datepicker like below

```
$("#dt1").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "../images/calender.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                $("#dt2").datepicker("show");
            }
        });

 $("#dt2").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "../images/calender.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                $("#dt1").datepicker("show");
            }
        });
```

Now what I was doing is, On selection of one datepicker I was opening another datepicker.

And while checking markup through firebug, I found that there was only one `datepicker div`which was handled for both of datepicker.

So by clicking on imageButton it will set that div's `display:block;` and focus is lost from there it will set that div's `display:none;`

So the issue was, While on selection of one datepicker it will show another datepicker, but after that onclose event of first datepicker will get called which will set that datepicker div's `display:none`. so second datepicker will not be visible.

Comment: what is a `funcrion`? paste error perhaps?

Comment: I tried to assemble a scenario here: http://jsfiddle.net/cwcU9/8/ But I could not replicate. Could you try to assemble a scenario we can access?

Comment: I added the bootstrap from cdn and it works http://jsfiddle.net/kgpYm/

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss :: it is `function`. Edited my question

Comment: @SagarJoshi just thought you should be aware of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330790/jquery-ui-in-conflict-with-bootstrap-in-css

Comment: @Sagar Joshi you can use div instaed of text box.see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188435/always-visible-jquery-ui-datepicker

Answer (score 0):

As a solution,

I open 2nd datepicker `onClose` of 1st datepicker instead of `onSelect`.

```
 $("#dt1").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "../images/calender.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            },
            onClose: function (dateText) {
                $('#dt2').focus();
            }
        });
```

Now it is working fine for me.