# Bootstrap Accordion Viciously Sliding Around When Integrated into CMS

Tags: css, html, wordpress, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

My developer added my style changes for a quick mobile version of a site since the deadline is so tight. I built it static and gave to him to implement into the CMS.

Well now the design is angry and I can't find why. I think something is going on with the CSS, my dev thinks it might be something with jQuery UI.

[THE LINK (our staging area)](http://clients.realintegrated.com/desertdiamond/www/#)

It's responsive so when you shrink the site down, my mobile build appears. The trouble comes when you start to click on Entertainment/Stay & Play/Dining/Gaming tiles. They're a very weird sliding around of these things and I can't lock down where the issue is coming from.

Anyone have any ideas on what's up?

Comment: What's it supposed to do?

Comment: The boxes accordion out into options for properties. What they're supposed to do works just fine. However the headers seem to be sliding all over one another near the bottom of the page one clicked. Start clicking and you'll see the weirdness.

Comment: Here's a CodePen of how it's supposed to function: http://codepen.io/bmoneruiux/full/6eb14c6e6fc671e27c70c5089b6ddd2c/

Comment: It seems jQuery UI's accordion element is interfering with the Bootstrap accordion element. However I've no idea how to counter this, and can't rename something that already exists in Bootstrap's coding.

Comment: This question might help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330790/jquery-ui-in-conflict-with-bootstrap-in-css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330790/jquery-ui-in-conflict-with-bootstrap-in-css)

Comment: Thanks much. I'll make sure to read this up and down.

Comment: Alex. Can you put that in answer form so I can accept it? It was indeed VERY helpful. However we also found the includes to jQuery UI and nixed the accordion portion of it.

Comment: Sure thing - I summed this up in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI's accordion and Bootstrap's accordion [may be in conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330790/jquery-ui-in-conflict-with-bootstrap-in-css) - in which case, you can make sure that jQuery UI Accordion isn't being included in the website, or download a special version of jQuery UI which is designed to [not conflict with Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15330864/3474146).

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm a foundation guy myself, and have never really worked with bootstrap until last week so I knew nothing about this issue.